# illegal shadowing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

can anyone tell me how this is illegal shadowing in JS?

```js
let a = 10;

{
  var a = 20;
}
```

What I know is var 'a' will be created at global space and let 'a' is created at script space. Both are different memory location so why above shadowing is not possible

Comment: vars are hoisted, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: `let` and `const` are blocked scoped, while `var` is function scoped (or global if not in a function). To solve your issue use `let` or `const` within the block. You current code is essentially the same as `let a = 10` followed by `var a = 10`, without the wrapping block.

Answer (score 3):

`var` is not scoped to the block it's in, it's scoped to the containing function. If there is no containing function, it ends up in the global scope. Hence it conflicts with the `let a` declaration which is also in the global scope.

Comment: but `let a` is in Script scope and not Global scope. 

Comment: @Yusuf In the code shown in the question, there is no `import` or `export` statement, so it's not an ES2015 module, hence there is no "script" (i.e. module) scope. So everything that's not local is global. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045/14637